# How to Change Application icon from coding in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, icons

I want to change my application icon daily from codeing just like  apple calendar app whaich shows daily date as icon of app.
i want same is it possible?

Comment: You can't change the icon of your app programmatically (or at least not in an official app - on a jailbroken device, or with private APIs, this may be possible.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible for third-party apps.

What the calendar app does is restricted to apps provided by Apple with elevated rights. It probably requires access to APIs that are private and not publicly documented. If you'd used them, your app wouldn't pass Apple's validation.